Command line link with VS 2022: fatal error C1905: Front end and back end not compatible (must target same processor)
I need to have a command line environment with Visual Studio 2022.
It's based on a set of Unix C-Shell like scripts (Hamilton C-Shell to be exact).
I managed to do that a long time ago with VS 2015, but when I attempt to replicate with 2022, I get the C1905 error at link.
I tried to set up the appropriate environment variables, using in VS the following: Tools -> Command Line -> Dev Command Prompt
In the opened shell, I use "set > env.txt" to see what VS has set up.
I derived from this "set" output the following script:

setenv VSINSTALLDIR 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community'
setenv VCINSTALLDIR 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC'
setenv FrameworkDir 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework'
setenv FrameworkVersion 'v4.0.30319'
setenv FrameworkVersion32 'v4.0.30319'
setenv Framework40Version 'v4.0'
setenv DevEnvDir 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Common7\IDE'
set vcc_path = 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.39.33519\bin\HostX86\x86;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Common7\IDE\VC\VCPackages;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Current\bin\Roslyn;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Common\VSPerfCollectionTools\vs2019;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.8 Tools;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\FSharp\Tools;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Team Tools\DiagnosticsHub\Collector;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.22621.0\x64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\x64;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\amd64;C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Common7\IDE;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Common7\Tools;C:\Program Files (x86)\VMware\VMware Workstation\bin;C:\Program Files\AdoptOpenJDK\jre-8.0.282.8-hotspot\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v10.2\bin;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v10.2\libnvvp;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files (x86)\Bitvise Tunnelier;C:\Program Files\Dyalog\Dyalog APL-64 13.2 Unicode;C:\Program Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;C:\Program Files (x86)\Bitvise SSH Client;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\Nsight Compute 2019.5.0;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin;C:\Program Files\dotnet;C:\Program Files\PuTTY;C:\Program Files (x86)\AOMEI\AOMEI Backupper\7.1.2;C:\Program Files\GitHub CLI;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\150\Tools\Binn;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\170\Tools\Binn;C:\Users\m1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Scripts;C:\Users\m1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311;C:\Users\m1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Scripts;C:\Users\m1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32;C:\Users\m1\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Program Files (x86)\IrScrutinizer;c:\Program Files\Saxonica\SaxonHE9.4N\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Dr. Memory\bin;C:\Users\m1.dotnet\tools;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\CMake\CMake\bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\CMake\Ninja;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Common7\IDE\VC\Linux\bin\ConnectionManagerExe'
setenv INCLUDE 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.39.33519\include;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.39.33519\ATLMFC\include;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Auxiliary\VS\include;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22621.0\ucrt;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22621.0\um;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22621.0\shared;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22621.0\winrt;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22621.0\cppwinrt;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um'
set EXTERNAL_INCLUDE 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.39.33519\include;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.39.33519\ATLMFC\include;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Auxiliary\VS\include;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22621.0\ucrt;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22621.0\um;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22621.0\shared;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22621.0\winrt;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22621.0\cppwinrt;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um'
setenv LIB 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.39.33519\ATLMFC\lib\x86;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.39.33519\lib\x86;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\lib\um\x86;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.22621.0\ucrt\x86;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.22621.0\um\x86'
setenv LIBPATH 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.39.33519\ATLMFC\lib\x86;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.39.33519\lib\x86;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.39.33519\lib\x86\store\references;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\UnionMetadata\10.0.22621.0;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\References\10.0.22621.0;C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319'

Compiling seems to work:

cl /nologo /MT /EHsc /D_CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D_CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE /c /Oi /Ot /Oy test.cpp -DWNT -ID:\m1\utc++
test.cpp

produces a test.obj file.
Linking does not:

link /LTCG /NOLOGO /FIXED:NO  test.obj  /INCREMENTAL:NO  D:\m1\utc++\utc-lib\x64\Release\utc-lib.lib SNMPAPI.LIB version.lib kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib odbc32.lib odbccp32.lib wsock32.lib msvcrt.lib msvcrtd.lib Shlwapi.lib /NODEFAULTLIB:libcmt  /OUT:test.exe


fatal error C1905: Front end and back end not compatible (must target same processor).
LINK : fatal error LNK1257: code generation failed

utc-lib.lib has been made within VS 2022 in a pretty standard way.
cl is here:

C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.39.33519\bin\HostX86\x86\cl.exe

link is here:

C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.39.33519\bin\HostX86\x86\link.exe

What am I missing?

Microsoft Developer Community gave me the answer: use \x64 instead of \x86 in the environment variables.
